# Send cursor to square of pixels

Tags: java, awtrobot

I'm trying to find a way to send the cursor to a square of pixels on the screen. Here, I've got some code that can send it to a specific position:

```
package JavaObjects;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;

public class MCur {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            // The cursor goes to these coordinates
            int xCoord = 500;
            int yCoord = 500;

            // This moves the cursor
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.mouseMove(xCoord, yCoord);
        } catch (AWTException e) {}
    }
}
```

Is there perhaps some way that, using similar code, I can establish a range rather than a specific point, such that the cursor goes to some random part of the established square?

Comment: Are you interested to know if ```java.util.Random``` exists? Yes, it does. Generating an ```x``` coordinate between ```xmin``` and ```xmax``` (inclusive): ```x=xmin+r.nextInt(xmax-xmin+1)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're working with as you say a "Square", you may want to use the java.awt.Rectangle class, if you're clicking buttons this is particularly useful as you can define the button boundary instead of a point.

As for the random radius, this is easily accomplished with java.util.Random

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.Random;

public class MoveMouse {

    private static final Robot ROBOT;
    private static final Random RNG;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // grab the screen size
        Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        // Equivalent to 'new Rectangle(0, 0, screen.width, screen.height)' 
        Rectangle boundary  = new Rectangle(screen);
        // move anywhere on screen
        moveMouse(boundary);
    }

    public static void moveMouse(int x, int y, int radiusX, int radiusY) {
        Rectangle boundary = new Rectangle();
        // this will be our center
        boundary.setLocation(x, y);
        // grow the boundary from the center
        boundary.grow(radiusX, radiusY);
        moveMouse(boundary);
    }

    public static void moveMouse(Rectangle boundary) {
        // add 1 to the width/height, nextInt returns an exclusive random number (0 to (argument - 1))
        int x = boundary.x + RNG.nextInt(boundary.width + 1);
        int y = boundary.y + RNG.nextInt(boundary.height + 1);
        ROBOT.mouseMove(x, y);
    }

    // initialize the robot/random instance once when the class is loaded
    // and throw an exception in the unlikely scenario when it can't 
    static {
        try {
            ROBOT = new Robot();
            RNG = new Random();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

This is a basic demonstration.

You may need to add negative/out-of-range value checks and so on so that it doesn't try to click off the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm getting it to compile, however when I go to run it, it says that there's not a class that has a static void main method accepting String[]. In the code I included above, I used the line "public static void main(String args[]) {" to fix this same issue, but when I use the line here I get a bunch of new errors, such as "insert enum Identifier" on the "static {" line. Would you happen to know what I could do? I understand these kinds of things are hard to diagnose in comments, if you don't happen to know off the top of your head that's fine

Comment: I've added the class imports/class body/main method however I strongly suggest focusing more on the syntax and basic language features before you attempt actually making anything.